# can't find the head file when compile rapidxml in ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, rapidxml

i want to parse xml by rapidxml(on android devices, NDK).
but when i include the rapidxml.hpp in my cpp file, and compile it. 
the compilor shows me that "jni/rapidxml.hpp:11:47: fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory". what's wrong with it?

the code and compile result followed.

source code:

`#include "rapidxml_utils.hpp"`

```
void test(){}
```

compile result:

`jni/rapidxml.hpp:11:47: fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make: * [obj/local/armeabi/objs/rapidxml/RapidXml.cpp,rapidxml.o] Error 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should also include the header file in your Android.mk using LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in your module.

Comment: The problem still exist after i add "LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include/" to Android.mk. something else i have missed?

Comment: Do you include rapidxml_utils.hpp in your module?

Comment: I have include rapidxml_utils.hpp. Now I set "LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(ANDROID_NDK_PATH)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include/", then it can find cstdlib. But it failed to find "bits/c++config.h" in cstdlib instead. I cant find the c++config.h in the same directory. the file appear in other directory such as "cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/x86/include/bits/c++config.h".

Comment: Do you have APP_STL := gnustl_static or APP_STL := stlport_static line in your Application.mk? You should not add those headers one by one.